# No access to this in prototype

Tags: javascript

Why does `this` alert as `undefined` in the code below?

http://jsfiddle.net/7kwXd/6/

```
var testObj = {};

testObj.aMethod = function() {
    this.testVar = "thing"
    alert(this.anObject.dimension1);
    alert(this.anObject.dimension2);
};

testObj.aMethod.prototype.anObject = {
   dimension1 : this.testVar,
   dimension2 : "thing2"
};

var testing = new testObj.aMethod();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an object (`{dimension1: this.testVar, dimension2: "thing2"}`) without any object context. What is `this` supposed to be at that time? After that, you are assigning it to `testObj.aMethod.prototype.anObject`.

You can use code like this to achieve what you want:

```
var testObj = {};

testObj.aMethod = function() {
    this.testVar = "thing"
    alert(this.anObject.dimension1);
    alert(this.anObject.dimension2);
};

testObj.aMethod.prototype.getAnObject = function() {
   return {
       dimension1 : this.testVar,
       dimension2 : "thing2"
   };
};

var testing = new testObj.aMethod();
```

And then access that object with `testing.getAnObject().dimension1`.